# Как скрыть только 1 компонент на странице, а не всю страницу React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Скажите, пожалуйста, как исправить код, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку не скрывалась вся страница, на которой находится эта функция?

мне нужно при нажатии на кнопку скрыть **ТОЛЬКО** компонент `<Notification />`
а `component1` и `component2` остаются, как и страница, на котрой они находятся

```
// функции
     
     
 const [hidden, setHidden] = useState(false);
 if (hidden) return null;
     
     <Component1 />
     
     <Notification title="заголовок">
        <Text weight="400" className={styles.text}>
      Текст
        </Text>
        <div className={styles.buttonContainer} >
        <Button className={styles.notificationButton} onClick={() => setHidden(true)}>
          OK!
        </Button>
        </div>
      </Notification>
      
  <Component2 />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте условие по выводу компонента

```
{variable && <Component />}
```

Если **variable** будет **true**, то **Component** будет отрисован

```
const [hidden, setHidden] = useState(false);

return (
  <Component1 />

{!hidden && <Notification title="заголовок">
  <Text weight="400" className={styles.text}>
    Текст
  </Text>
  <div className={styles.buttonContainer} >
    <Button className={styles.notificationButton} onClick={() => setHidden(true)}>
      OK!
    </Button>
  </div>
</Notification>}

<Component2 />
)
```

Второй вариант, можно по условию показывать тот или иной компонент, с помощью тернарного оператора

```
{variable ? (<Component1>) : (<Component2>)}
```

В вашем коде это будет выглядеть так

```
return (
  <Component1 />

{!hidden ? (<Notification title="заголовок">
  <Text weight="400" className={styles.text}>
    Текст
  </Text>
  <div className={styles.buttonContainer} >
    <Button className={styles.notificationButton} onClick={() => setHidden(true)}>
      OK!
    </Button>
  </div>
</Notification>) 
: (<div>Нет уведомлений</div>)}

<Component2 />
)
```

Comment: о боже, спасибо большое! все сработало :)
отмечу ответ как верный через 5 мин - пока не получается, пишет, что через 5мин можно будет :D

Comment: @Marie Обновил ответ, добавил второй вариант условного рендера

Comment: супер! спасибо огромное!